# How to implement order_by and group_by on the same mysql queryset in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-filter

I have one Image model and Resized_Image model where I will resize my original image into different sizes and store them in the Resized_Image model. When I am trying to filter the data it is giving duplicate results.

Here is my Model:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=40,unique=True,help_text="name of the image")
    status = StatusField()

class Resized_image(models.Model):
    img = models.ForeignKey(Image, related_name='images', on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to=date_format,width_field='width', height_field='height',)
    width=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    height=models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

My serializer:

```
class resized_imagesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = Resized_image
       fields = ('image','width','height')

class imagesSerializer(QueryFieldsMixin,serializers.ModelSerializer):

   images =resized_imagesSerializer(many=True,required=False,read_only=True)
   image = Base64ImageField(write_only=True,)
   class Meta:
       model = Image
       fields = ('id','name','image','status','images')
       required = ['image']
```

My view:

```
class ImageListView(mixins.CreateModelMixin,generics.ListAPIView):
     queryset = Image.objects.all()
     serializer_class = imagesSerializer
     def get_queryset(self):
        param = self.request.query_params.get("width", None)
        queryset = Image.objects.order_by(*param) 

     return queryset
```

My result without any filtering:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "abc",
    "status": 0,
    "images": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "image": "/images/photos/2019/04/29/14b77119-5d7.png",
            "width": 720,
            "height": 200
           },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "image": "/images/photos/2019/04/29/Movies/medium/14b77119-5d7.png",
            "width": 720,
            "height": 1280

        }
    ]
}
```

Here when I have multiple images with different resized images, If I try to do order by based on width I am getting duplicate results(image with id 1 is repeating twice) How to do group_by on the ordered queryset using Django.
I have used annotate but that is also giving the same result.

```
Image.objects.order_by(*ordering).annotate(Count('id'))
```

Comment: try **`distinct()`**

Comment: I tried using distict() still same result. My query looks like this

SELECT DISTINCT `image_app_image`.`id`, `image_app_image`.`name`, `image_app_image`.`status`, `image_app_resized_image`.`size` FROM `image_app_image` LEFT OUTER JOIN `image_app_resized_image` ON (`image_app_image`.`id` = `image_app_resized_image`.`img_id`) ORDER BY `image_app_resized_image`.`size` ASC

Comment: How to make the query as INNER JOIN instead of LEFT OUTER JOIN ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a subquery

```
min_query =
    Resized_image.objects.filter(image_id=OuterRef('id'))
    .order_by('width')
    .values('width', 'height', 'image')[:1]

Image.objects.all().annotate(
    width=Subquery(
        min_query.values('width'))
    ).annotate(
    height=Subquery(
        min_query.values('height'))
    ).annotate(
    image=Subquery(
        min_query.values('image'))
    )
```

Comment: It was missing 2 brackets sorry